# Getting and using parent directory through ANT

Tags: php, ant, phpunit, relative-path, build.xml

I have a directory structure & build.xml like this

```
    /path-to-project/src/prj1
    /path-to-project/src/prj2

    /path-to-project/tests
    /path-to-project/tests/build.xml
```

I have to somehow get the path

```
    /path-to-project/
```

in my build.xml

My build.xml is like this

```
<project name="php-project-1" default="build" basedir=".">
  <property name="source" value="src"/>
    <target name="phploc" description="Generate phploc.csv">
      <exec executable="phploc">
        <arg value="--log-csv" />
        <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />
        <arg path="${source}" />
      </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Here I somehow want to get value of `${source}` as `/path-to-project/src/` but I am not getting it with `${parent.dir}`

Is it possible to get this path in the build.xml?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `..` just as you do on the command-line to navigate to the parent directory.

```
<project name="php-project-1" default="build" basedir=".">
  <property name="root.dir" location=".."/>
  <property name="source" location="${root.dir}/src"/>
  ...
</project>
```

**Update:** Changed `value` to `location` as per martin's answer which you should accept.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `location` attribute rather than `value` to set the `source` property:

```
<property name="source" location="src"/>
```

Ant will then set the property to the absolute path of the given location.  If the the location looks like a relative path, the absolute path is calculated relative to basedir.  The [`property` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) has other attributes you can use to tune this further.

To get the parent directory of your basedir, you can similarly use:

```
<property name="parent.dir" location=".." />
```

*(at least on a unix machine, not tested on windows.)*

Comment: +1 for the great info on `location`. This should clean up my build files a little. :)

Comment: @martin - thanks for the info on location. It made few things very clear now. Thnks!!